# How to Store Cookies in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, cookies, storage

I am programmatcally accessing authenticated content in my CDN on Google App Engine, and it's returning a cookie that I'm supposed to store:

```
{"set-cookie"=>"ACSID=cookie-hash; expires=Mon, 12-Apr-2010 01:56:06 GMT; path=/"}
```

What do I do with that?  This is my first time dealing with Cookies.

I can put in the header of the next request, but what's the recommended way to store that?  I'm testing this with irb in the console and when I exit and try again, the cookie is gone.

How do I save it for a few days/weeks?  I'm using pure ruby without Rails or anything.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Ruby Mechanize](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/mechanize/) has a [cookie jar](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/mechanize/Mechanize/CookieJar.html) and [cookie](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/mechanize/Mechanize/Cookie.html) class.  It's fairly straight forward, and seems independent from the rest of the library.  You construct and [add](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/mechanize/Mechanize/CookieJar.html#add-method) cookies, specifying the URL, and later you use the [cookies](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/mechanize/Mechanize/CookieJar.html#cookies-method) method to check which cookies apply to a given URL.  You can serialize the jar with [save_as](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/mechanize/Mechanize/CookieJar.html#save-as-method) and deserialize with [load](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/mechanize/Mechanize/CookieJar.html#load-method).